# Wordpress Avada Theme page title bar background image link to article/Post

Tags: wordpress

maybe sombody could help me.

I`m working on the Avada Theme now to use as a blog and have an image in page title bar which I would like to link/clickable to an article.

Anybody who can give me an idea?

Comment: show us what you have tried and indicate where you are facing problem in the code

Comment: I do not tried as much, I just tried to set an link via html like: <a href="link"><img src="url to img.jpg" alt="img" /></a>. but of course its not working